# matplotlib "DLL load failed" when import pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib. My environment is WinXP, PythonWin 2.6.2, NumPy 1.3.0, matplotlib 0.98.5.3.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 253, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 75, in <module>
    new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, show = pylab_setup()
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tkagg                 # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    import _tkagg
ImportError: DLL load failed: cannot find the module
```

I searched the web and it's said because lack of msvcp71.dll, but there is already one in my C:\windows\system32\

anyone can help?
Thanks.

Comment: Please report this on the matplotlib-users mailing list. The build for Python 2.6 on Windows is very new, so it is not surprising if it has problems in some environments.

Answer (score 8):

try this, before using any other module

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
```

see http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05372.html for more details and other ways

matplotlib can use different backends for rendering, agg is pure draw with no UI, so you can only save images e.g.

```
plt.savefig("plt.png")
```

read http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/installing_faq.html#what-is-a-backend for more details, e.g. you can output to ps, pdf, wxagg, tkagg etc, so if you have wxpython installed use this

```
matplotlib.use('wxagg')
```

also i think tkagg backend should have been work, as tkinter(http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) is default gui with python, did you install python from python.org?

Comment: yes, with this the dll load error disappears. but nothing comes up when I typed following example scripts. it should show up a window with image, right? >>> import matplotlib >>> matplotlib.use("Agg") >>> import matplotlib.pylab as pylab >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt >>> plt.plot([1,2,3])  >>> plt.ylabel("some") >>> plt.show()

Comment: modified answer, see why you don't see anything

Comment: yes, I can save png file with "Agg". I am just curious why it cannot use "TkAgg". I am using PythonWin2.6.2, and pass the basic Tkinter test: >>> import _tkinter >>> import Tkinter >>> Tkinter._test( ). But once use("TkAgg"), import pylab fails with "DLL load failed" as in my first question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing activestat python 2.6 and pylab. After installing the sourceforge python 2.6.2 however it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer and the graphs are running great on my computer. If you are getting a DLL error like this, try downloading msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll in your computer and then copy paste these two in your System32 folder:

> C:\Windows\System32

and also copy-paste these two dll's in SysWOW64 folder if you are working on 64bit operating System

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Now try running your code file in Python and it will load the graph in couple of seconds. Here is the link which says how to copy-paste dll's to both folder, this might help

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmvRF7koJ5E

Cheers...

Comment: Just so you know, this question was posted over 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using iPython notebooks using Python 2.7. Apparently the latest Seaborn update does not play well with my local configuration settings, so I did "conda/pip install seaborn=0.5.1". It downgraded the necessary packages automatically, and my problem went away.